# Will order matters when there's specificity exists?

Tags: css, hover, css-specificity

I was making a menu list for current page (`.active`), and here's my first try:

```
.menu li:hover,
.menu li:focus {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
}

.menu li.active {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #888;
}
```

(For clean page here, I put all on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/weyezo/edit?html,css,output).)

However, the hovering effect about tab is not shown as what I want. So I changed the order of the two like below.

```
.menu li.active {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #888;
}

.menu li:hover,
.menu li:focus {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
}
```

Also on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/jikepew/edit?html,css,output)

Cheers! It now works as I wanted. But the question comes to my mind.

The specificity of `.menu li.active` is **higher** than the `.menu li:hover`, basically 20 vs 11. But why it only works when `.menu li.active` is before the `.menu li:hover` (the second area of code above)?

Is that because, for the code area 1, we specified the border color of `.menu li:hover` first, then we meet the `.menu li.active`, and it's border color is not specified when hovering?

(Don't know it's clear or not. It's kinda hard to explain.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes and pseudo-classes have the same specificity. `.menu li.active` therefore has the same 'weight' as `.menu li:hover`.

Formula, explained (among others) on [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) and [CSS Tricks: Specifics on CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/):

> Memorize how to measure specificity. “Start at 0, add 1000 for style
>   attribute, add 100 for each ID, add 10 for each attribute, class or
>   pseudo-class, add 1 for each element name or pseudo-element. So in
>   `body #content .data img:hover` the specificity value would be 122
>   (0,1,2,2 or 0122): 100 for `#content`, 10 for `.data`, 10 for `:hover`, 1
>   for `body` and 1 for `img`.”

Applied to your CSS, it would give `21` for both selectors. In case of equal weight, the order is important and the last rule is used.

To make the rule more specific, you can have `.menu li.active` for the 'default' styling, and `.menu li.active:hover` for the hovered version. The latter is more specific (31 vs 21) than the first and will always be applied on hovering, not matter the order in the CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

> Will order matters when there's specificity exists?

Only when specificity is equal.

> The specificity of .menu li.active is higher than the .menu li:hover, basically 20 vs 11

No, it isn't.

[Classes and pseudo-classes have equal specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity).

So both are 021 (No id selectors, two class or psuedo-class selectors and one type selector).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the weight of your `CSS rules`, [here](http://specificity.keegan.st/), both of your rules are same about weight (both are 0 0 2 1)